# window.close is not working in IE 6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

I am using window.close() for closing window by clicking on button its not working in IE 6. Is there any jquery solution

Comment: jQuery can not solve every problem one is facing in a webinterface. window.close is a very simple command. My guess is that your code to call the window.close is wrong. Please post it.

Comment: If you can post the sample code please post it.

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery is awesome!  You can call one method to do something and it will work in all modern browsers](http://www.nabble.com/jQuery-function-to-close-a-window-td18350647s27240.html):

```
$(window).each(function(){ this.close() })
```

`</sarcasm>`

Answer (score 1):

Its not an issue with IE. Use the correct code. Check [Using window.close](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-close.phtml)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be where you are using the window.close.

You have to make sure that the window object is referring to the current object, ie If you have a parent and child window and you are trying to call window.close from the parent the window object will be the parent window.

Make sure that the window object is corrent